# Xamarin Checkbox isn't "linking" properly to ObservableCollection in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm, having a Listview, with bunch of "Modules" in one ObservableCollection, which has been set as the ItemsSource. This collection has been set as:

`public static ObservableCollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }`  in App.xaml.cs to make it global.

When I click the checkbox in the list, it will launch this function:

```
private void ModuleCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

            var item = (Module)checkbox.BindingContext;
            item.ModuleIsChecked = checkbox.IsChecked;

            foreach(Module m in App.Modules)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Name + " Value: " + m.ModuleIsChecked);        
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set the property: `ModuleIsChecked` to be the same, as the checkbox, which in this case should be true or false. Now, when I click the checkbox, and the foreach-loop goes trough, the values are correct. When I go to the new "page" by using the 
`Navigation.PushAsync(new NewSite());` function and run the loop again, none of the Modules have `ModuleIsChecked` value as set before. How is this possible?

Module has the following attributes:

```
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
        public bool ModuleIsChecked { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Question> QuestionList { get; set; }
```

**edit** as requested, here's the code at the new page, where I run through the same list just to see, if my selections have been "stuck" into that ObservableCollection:

```
public partial class NewSite : ContentPage
    {

        public Questions()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new App();

            foreach(Module m in App.Modules)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Module: {0} ModuleisChecked: {1}", m.Name, m.ModuleIsChecked);
            }
```

And here, the Console shows, that all of the values are False. Any ideas?

Comment: why aren't you just binding ModuleIsChecked to the checkbox?

Comment: Hi! The isChecked is binded to the ModuleIsChecked like this:
<CheckBox Grid.Column ="1" x:Name="ModuleCheckbox" IsChecked="{Binding ModuleIsChecked}" CheckedChanged="ModuleCheckbox_CheckedChanged"></CheckBox>

In the XML-page.

Comment: Then why are you also setting it in the event handler?

Comment: Because for some reason it is not working. At the new page, I run trought the loop just to check if all my "selections" have been saved, but they all are False, which is the default when creating Modules into that Observable Collection. I'm quite new to Xamarin, so please excuse my ignorance, if I don't know what you mean :)

Comment: Please show the relevant code from page2

Comment: You are creating a new instance of App instead of using the existing instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Jason in the comments! (I don't know how to link you here, sorry!)

The problem lies in here:

```
BindingContext = new App();
```

As Jason said, that creates new instance of the App instead of using the existing one, which I just edited. Commenting this out and I was able to get this working as intended. Thank you!

Can be marked as solved, thanks!